# I can't push files with Chinese names such as "hello你好.txt" through Windows adb command line

Tags: android, adb

The failure message:

```
failed to copy 'D:\My Documents\桌面\hello你好.txt' to '/storage/sdcard0/hello你好.txt': Invalid argument
```

The other problem I have suffered from is similar to this one, which the message displayed in the command line "adb shell ls" is weird and totally wrong when it comes to chinese file items, however the english items are displayed normally.

```
android
test.txt
鎴戠殑鐓х墖
鎴戠殑瑙嗛
鎴戠殑闊充箰
root@android:/storage/sdcard0 #
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is：

```
D:\My Documents\桌面\hello你好.txt
```

The above path format is for Windows. And:

```
/storage/sdcard0/hello你好.txt
```

path format is for *NIX.

You could try replace `D:\My Documents\桌面\hello你好.txt` with `D:/My Documents/桌面/hello你好.txt` or `/D/My Documents/桌面/hello你好.txt`.

The second problem is because the encoding, try change your Terminal encoding.